# iterating over a tuple containing one string actually iterates over characters

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, tuples

I've noticed a weird behavior when iterating over a tuple containing only 1 string:

```
foo = ("hello")
for entry in foo:
    print(entry)
```

outputs:

```
h
e
l
l
o
```

But I expect here to iterate only once, and output "hello" in a row.

If my tupple contains 2 entries, that's what happening:

```
foo = ("hello", "world!")
for entry in foo:
    print(entry)
```

outputs:

```
hello
world!
```

Is it a bug in CPython's implementation? 
Even weirder, this doesn't occur if I use a list instead of a tuple:

```
foo = ["hello"]
for entry in foo:
    print(entry)
```

outputs:

```
hello
```

Comment: `('hello')` **is not** a tuple containing one string. It's just a string. Try `print(type(foo))`.

Comment: To expand on jonrsharpes comment, the correct way to define a 1 element tuple would be ('hello',)

Comment: `foo = 'hello',` would be enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`("hello")` is not a tuple - it's a string, surrounded with parenthesis, which are meaningless in this context. If you want a single-element tuple, you need a comma after the value:

```
foo = ("hello",) 
# Here--------^
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

You have a string not a tuple:

```
>>> type(('hello'))
<class 'str'>
>>> type(('hello',))
<class 'tuple'>
```